# AndroidRuntimeException when a hyperlink is clicked in dialog shown on first run

Tags: android, android-activity

My main activity checks to see if it's the first time the user has run the app in its onCreate method.  In the dialog, which is a WebView, there's a hyperlink for sending email back to me.  When the user clicks on the link, though, I'm getting the following exception:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:651)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:258)
        at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:235)
        at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:330)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The Activity causing the exception is set up like this in the manifest file:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is the code that creates the dialog:

```
private Dialog createFirstRunDialog() {
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflator.inflate(R.layout.tutorial, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.tutorialMain));

    WebView webView = (WebView)layout.findViewById(R.id.tutorialBody);
    webView.loadUrl(TUTORIAL_HTML_FILE);

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setView(layout)
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setTitle(R.string.tutorial_title)
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.tutorial_doneButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dismissDialog(TUTORIAL_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
    return dialogBuilder.create();
}
```

The link within the html (inside an asset) is a typical mailto link:

```
    <a href="mailto:support@myapp.com?subject=MyApp feature request">Tell us</a>
```

As the dialog is built with an AlertDialog.Builder and not an explicit Intent (not actually calling startActivity explicitly), I'm unable [as far as I'm aware] to add the flag as the exception message states.  I found some posts here with a similar exception, but none were the same or had fixes that solved my issue.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to intercept the link and handle it yourself.

```
WebView webView = (WebView)layout.findViewById(R.id.tutorialBody);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
            MailTo mt = MailTo.parse(url);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("text/html");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {mt.getTo()});
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mt.getSubject());
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Email ..."));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
webView.loadUrl(TUTORIAL_HTML_FILE);
```