# AndroidRuntimeException from Google Play Crash Report

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an app on the Google play store and it works fine for most people.  However there are 90 crashes reported, via Google crash report, with the following:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:847)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:276)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:242)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:330)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4429)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:3151)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:2918)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've had a look around on the web but all I can find is to add `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`.

But this doesn't work for me as I don't call `startActivity()` in my code.  I do call `startActivityForResult()` but specifying the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag stops the result being returned in `onActivityResult()`.

Here is the only piece of code that has `startActivityForResult()` called from `onCreate()` in my Main Activity:

```
private void load()
{
    Intent loadBeats = new Intent(this, BeatListActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(loadBeats, SELECT_BEAT_ACTIVITY);
}
```

I've never actually had this error occur for me on any of my devices or in a Virtual Device!  This all makes it difficult to solve.

Any ideas?

Comment: The 'webkit' is a bit of a clue. See this Q&A : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481178/androidruntimeexception-when-a-hyperlink-is-clicked-in-dialog-shown-on-first-run

Comment: @ReubenScratton not sure how this relates.  I don't use URLs and my app starts from the icon, which launches the main Activity.

Comment: Do you have a WebView anywhere in your project?

Comment: I don't have WebView anywhere in my project.

Comment: Do you use any third party libraries that might contain WebViews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the helpful comments, @ReubenScratton, following my question I think I've found the problem/solution!

In my code I do not use `startActivity()` so this confused me.  However I do use AdView (admob adverts) version 4.1.1, which does seem to call `startActivity()`.
I found this out after searching Google.  Other people had reported the same errors, as per my question, using that version of AdView (GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4-1-1.jar).

I've updated my app with a newer version and, so far, there have been no more errors!

I will report back if this is not the case thought.

Answer (score 0):

Just Adding up

This exception also happens with interstitial ads

You have to pass the activity context not application context

```
InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
```

Incase of fragments

```
InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
```

and not

```
InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```